# Taking all items from listview to textview on click

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textview, items

im a beginner in android/java programming and im trying to retrieve the element from a listview and put them in a textview.I know you can set text to a textview using settext but I dont know how to retrieve element from my listview(they are all strings) and put them in my textview

thank you

Comment: get the adapter from the list view.  The adapter gives you access to the data presented in the ListView

Comment: And how do I put adapter content in a textview? thanks

Comment: See my answer below.  I extract the list content into a StingBuffer and then apply it to the textview by calling the setText method on the textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuffer allItems = new StringBuffer();

Adapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
for (int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    Object item = adapter.getItem(i);
    allItems.append(item.toString());
    allItems.append(", ");
}

textView.setText(allItems.toString());
```

Comment: thank you, however I get error "The method add(String) is undefined for the type StringBuffer" at the ".add" statement?

Comment: oops - it should be "append".  I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! and is it possible to make that with content of 2 listview?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever content you want in the string buffer.